# SASS/SCSS classlist argument in mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have made a mixin, for making some grid colums in a min/max media query. Looks like this:

```
@mixin woo-grid($min: 0px, $max: 9999px, $cols: 3, $class: '') {

@media only screen and (min-width: $min) and (max-width: $max){
    .woocommerce, #{$class}{
        ul.products[class*="columns"]{
            margin-right: -2%;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        ul.products[class*="columns"] li.product{
            width: (100% / $cols) - 2% ;
            margin-right: 2%;
            margin-left: 0px;
            &:nth-of-type(#{$cols}n+#{$cols}){
                width: (100% / $cols) - 2% ;
                clear: right ;
                float: right;
            }

            &:nth-of-type(#{$cols}n+1){
                width: (100% / $cols) - 2% ;
                clear: both !important;
                float: left;
            }
            @for $i from 2 through $cols{
                @if($i != $cols){
                    &:nth-of-type(#{$cols}n+#{$i}){
                        width: (100% / $cols) - 2% ;
                        clear: none !important;
                        float: left;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

How it's used:

```
@include woo-grid(480px, 769px, 2, '.product-slider-section );
```

Now if I pass several selectors to the last argument nothing but the last selector will get the nested styles.

Example from the `li.product` styling with 2 selectors:

```
@include woo-grid(480px, 769px, 2, '.product-slider-section, .product-cats' );
```

will output the following selector in CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products[class*="columns"] li.product:nth-of-type(2n+1),
.product-slider-section, 
.product-cats ul.products[class*="columns"] li.product:nth-of-type(2n+1)
```

The first selector of the `$class` argument get completely ignored in all nested styles.

Am I doing something terribly wrong? Or is this just not possible in SASS?

Comment: If I put it in Sassmeister it compiles correctly: https://www.sassmeister.com/ Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Leafo's scssPHP [https://github.com/leafo/scssphp](https://github.com/leafo/scssphp) but a very outdated version. Updating should likely fix the issue.

Comment: Updating could never hurt. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else viewing this thread:

I updated Leafo's scssPHP to the newest version, which solved the classlist issue. It did however introduce another minor issue with some variable scoping, but that was easy to work around.